# List of list of named parameters in EJBQL/HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, jpa, hql

I'm trying to execute a long `'INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'` with up to a few thousand rows in a MySQL+JBoss+Hibernate application. It looks something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES
(value1_1, value2_1, value3_1),
(value1_2, value2_2, value3_2),
(value1_3, value2_3, value3_3),
...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

This works fine as a native query where I build up the query string in a loop, but the long query strings themselves are retained in the Hibernate query plan cache and eat up a lot of heap space. So I'm wondering if it's possible to parameterize this query so that it's stored only once in the query plan cache.

Is there a way to parameterize a list of tuples like this? Ideally I could pass in a collection of `{ value1, value2, value3 }` collections in `setParameter()`. It's easy enough to run thousands of one-line updates with `(:value1, :value2, :value3)`, but that comes at a significant (2-3x) performance cost.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Hibernate batch inserts](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts) section of the docs.